# How to find uses-feature in APK?

Tags: android, apk

I know I can use

```
aapt d permissions foo.apk
```

to find out which permissions a certain APK needs. But how can I check which `<uses-feature>` tags were used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`aapt dump badging` will list `<uses-feature>` as part of its output:

```
feature-group: label=''
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.camera'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.camera.front'
  uses-feature-not-required: name='android.hardware.microphone'
  uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
  uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
```